# uploading converted image to server

Tags: php

Below you can see the script that, if a user provides a `.jpg`-file, uploads it to the server directly, but when the user provides a `.png`-file, uploads it as well and then converts it to `.jpg`.

```
 $path = $_FILES["uploaded_image"]["name"];
 $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); //extracts file extension

 $tempimgloc = $_FILES["uploaded_image"]["tmp_name"];

 $imagepic = ''.$_SESSION['userid'].'-'.$_SESSION['username'].'.'.$ext.'';
 $img_url = 'img/uploaded/'.$imagepic.'';


 if($ext == 'jpg'){
 move_uploaded_file($tempimgloc, "img/uploaded/".$imagepic);
 mysql_query('UPDATE table SET img = "'.$img_url.'" WHERE id = '.$_SESSION['userid'].'');
 } elseif($ext == 'png'){
 move_uploaded_file($tempimgloc, "img/uploaded/".$imagepic);
 mysql_query('UPDATE table SET img = "'.$img_url.'" WHERE id = '.$_SESSION['userid'].'');

 $input_file = 'img/uploaded/'.$_SESSION['userid'].'-'.$_SESSION['username'].'.png';
 $output_file = 'img/uploaded/'.$_SESSION['userid'].'-'.$_SESSION['username'].'.jpg';

 $input = imagecreatefrompng($input_file);
 list($width, $height) = getimagesize($input_file);
 $output = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
 $white = imagecolorallocate($output,  255, 255, 255);
 imagefilledrectangle($output, 0, 0, $width, $height, $white);
 imagecopy($output, $input, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
 imagejpeg($output, $output_file);
```

What I would like to know is how to upload that new converted `.jpg` (`imagejpeg($output, $output_file)`) to my server. Do I use `move_uploaded_file` as well? Thanks!

PS: I know, MySQL is outdated and dangerous, will change that asap!

Comment: Yes, you would use `move_uploaded_file()`. Thanks for recognizing the outdated `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: I cannot really figure out how to use `move_uploaded_file()` to upload the new file. Could you maybe give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
$output_file = 'img/uploaded/'.$_SESSION['userid'].'-'.$_SESSION['username'].'.jpg';
```

to

```
$output_file = 'img/uploaded/'.$_SESSION['userid'].'-'.$_SESSION['username'].'.'.$ext;
```

The problem is with your output file extension

And your function

```
imagejpeg($output, $output_file);
```

Comment: but that does not upload it to my server, does it? What I need to know is how to use `move_uploaded_file()` or another function to upload the new converted image to my server.

Comment: No it does'nt you should move it then

Comment: That is my question, how do I move it? Could you show me?

Comment: This is the description on using it <br> http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/8/10/0

Comment: The parametrs are told <br> move_uploaded_file ( stringfilename, string destination)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68816/discussion-between-sehetmich-and-mehrdad-garebaghi).